# Redefine a C function in C++

Tags: c++, c, error-handling, redefinition

I have a C library with a function

```
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif

void exitWithError(const char* func) {
    printf("woopsie in %s", func);
    exit(1);
}

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif
```

`exitWithError` is exclusively called by other C code internal to the library.
The C library is always compiled in "C mode", i.e. via `g++ -x c ...`, conforming to C99, so cannot feature any C++ code. (I've realised now this makes the `#ifdef __cplusplus` check completely superfluous, but ho-hum, not relevant here).

I'm seeking to redefine `exitWithError` in a C++14 project which uses this C library, so that I can change how errors are handled (see my [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58550903/override-c-code-to-throw-a-c-exception)). This would change the C library's internal behaviour. I am trying to avoid change to the underlying C library code, but that's not a strict necessity.

It turns out I can, in my calling C++ code, simply override the behaviour of `exit` with

```
extern "C" void exit(int status) {
    throw 1;
}
```

This works great, but features the C `exitWithError` function calling `printf`. I wish to remove that behaviour, so nothing is printed when the C library invokes `exitWithError`.

Trying to redefine `exitWithError` with the same trick...

```
extern "C" void exitWithError(const char* func) {
    throw 1;
}
```

causes a `duplicate symbol` error during compiling, naturally.

What about `exit` enabled it to be redefined? Is there any way to "undefine" `exitWithError` so that the calling C++ code can redefine it?

I suspect I could pass an additional compiler flag (e.g. `-DSILENCE_FOOL`) when compiling the C library for use in my C++ project, and modify the C library code to

```
void exitWithError(const char* func) {
#ifndef SILENCE_FOOL
    printf("woopsie in %s", func);
#endif
    exit(1);
}
```

but I'd prefer a method without any modification to the C code.

And finally, is there a more sensible way (refactoring the C library) to allow users of the C library to "hook in" or override the `exitWithError` behaviour? It's a function invoked when the user supplies incorrect arguments (in my C++ code, I'll override it with `std::invalid_argument`).

Comment: `a duplicate symbol error` - so just make the symbol weak `objcopy --weak-symbol` or `--wrap` with gnu linker. `What about exit enabled it to be redefined?` - This works, because linker picks your version before the system version. I assume you are asking specifically about gcc compiler and linux environment.

Comment: *"What about exit enabled it to be redefined?"* See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50898508/can-a-declaration-affect-the-std-namespace

Comment: _"What about `exit` enabled it to be redefined?"_ It is in a library.

Comment: Even better than a special compiler flag, why not check for *__cplusplus* itself? That would still of course require modifying the C code, though.

Comment: @Chipster as alluded to, it seems compiling in C mode means __cplusplus isn't defined

Comment: Correct, so a `#ifndef` should work unless I'm mistaken (which I can often be).

Comment: @Chipster no, because __cplusplus is *never* defined; I *always* compile the underlying library in C mode (necessarily), and use it from my C++ code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I can, in my calling C++ code, simply override the behaviour of exit with
>
> ```
> extern "C" void exit(int status) {
>     throw 1; }
> ```

`exit` is an identifier reserved by the C standard library, and `void exit(int)` is a function signature reserved by thexitWithErrore C++ standard library. So, unless your target system is freestanding, this definition violates the language standard.

> Trying to redefine exitWithError with the same trick...
>
> ```
> extern "C" void exitWithError(const char* func) {
>     throw 1;
> }
> ```

This violates the one definition rule. There may be at most one definition for a function (exceptions apply, but none that are of help to you).

> Is there any way to "undefine" exitWithError so that the calling C++ code can redefine it?

Nothing in standard C or C++.

> What about exit enabled it to be redefined?

Some compilers, such as GCC, have a feature called "weak symbol"s, which allows the linker to choose from multiple different definitions. The C standard library that you used probably defines `exit` as such weak symbol.

You could use the same technique to declare the C library definition of `exitWithError` weak. But like the other solutions, this also requires modification of the library. Note that this approach is non-standard both when replacing `exit` and when replacing the library function.

---

> is there a more sensible way (refactoring the C library) to allow users of the C library to "hook in" or override the exitWithError behaviour?

You can introduce polymorphism with a function pointer. Example:

```
// in library (C):
void exitWithErrorDefault(const char* func) {
    printf("woopsie in %s", func);
    exit(1);
}

typedef void errorHandler_f(const char*);
errorHandler_f* exitWithErrorHandler = exitWithErrorDefault;

void exitWithError(const char* func) {
    exitWithErrorHandler(func);
}

// usage (C++)
void exitWithErrorCpp(const char* func) {
    throw 1; // bad
}
int main()
{
    exitWithErrorHandler = exitWithErrorCpp;
```

It is generally a bad idea to throw in a function called from C. C has no exceptions and C functions are generally not exception safe. It is quite typical for this to result in memory or other resource leak.

In this particular case, there's probably no attempt to release resources after call to `exitWithError` anyway since it's expected to terminate the process. If you don't attempt to continue the process after catching the exception, then you probably don't need to care about a leak.

Comment: I think the reason `exit` can be redefined is most likely to be that it's defined in a library.

Comment: @user253751 `exitWithError` is also in a library.

Comment: What kind of library? A .a file, or .so?

Comment: @user253751 OP did not specify.

Comment: I ask because I suspect it is not actually a library; it might be a library in the sense of "code they got from somewhere else" but I suspect it's being compiled as part of the same program.