# Override printf function

Tags: c++, c, weak-symbol

I have to override the standard printf function and implement it in a user-specific way. I have tried it as follows:

```
extern "C" int printf(const char* format, ...)
{
    // user specific implementation
}
```

With gcc, this code can be built. Visual Studio aborts the build with the following error message:

> Error C2084 function '`int printf(const char *const ,...)`' already has a body

Thanks you for any hints

Comment: _Why_ exactly do you have to do this? What problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: It's C++ code that uses printf to create a test monitor interface. This printf outputs must be forwarded to the user interface (.net core wpf app) in a Windows simulation.

Comment: As I understand it, functions from the standard library would only need to be linked if they do not exist in the project. At least that's how it's handled in gcc.

Comment: Functions are not like `virtual` class methods. You can't *override* functions, only *overload* them, or possibly *detour* them.

Comment: Create your own `my_printf()` function and then use `int my_printf(const char *const ,...);  #define printf my_printf` in files you want to override the default.

Comment: I don't see how it can be possible to do what you are hoping to do without also disabling linking and use of the C standard library. Even then, I suspect that trying to define these symbols is likely a form of undefined behavior -- and so `gcc` compiling this successfully is likely just coincidental

Comment: From what I can find, any definition of a C-standard library symbol violates ODR and also is using an identifier and signature that is reserved by the C standard library -- which would be undefined behavior ([source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58595833/1678770)). Your best bet is to define a custom function and use that

Comment: You are not allowed to provide your own version of any standard library functions (with a few exceptions not relevant here). You **might** get away with it through linker games, but that is not portable.

Comment: @PeteBecker Can you provide a source for that claim? All linkers I know only include definitions of not-yet-resolved references, and this is commonly well defined and documented.

Comment: And that's how I would have expected it from Visual Studio!

Comment: @Human-Compiler: gcc provides the functions as [**weak** symbols](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weak_symbol) to allow user replacement.

Comment: You could start your application from another one in a pipe with something like `popen` and reroute the error output channel to the regular one. That way, the output lands in a buffer instead of the console and you can do whatever you want. A kind of convoluted solution, but if you are interested, I can post some code.

Comment: I would try rerouting the output at the file descriptor level, or even start the C++ part in a separate process rather than (I assume) P/Invoking it. Fiddling with source-level output functions sounds like a game of whack-a-mole to me.

Comment: there's no weak symbol in MSVC

Comment: If you really want to do this, you have to hook the API.